# Why ajax calls error function, if I add this code?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have jquery script, it posts some data to servlet. Script calls success function, if servlet has only one string of code - `response.getWriter().print("message");`. If I try to set response content type or flush output stream, anything else, script calls error function. Why?

Here is code of script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login-button").click(function () {
            var userPassword = $("input#userPassword").val();
            var userLogin = $("input#userLogin").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {login: userLogin, password: userPassword},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Successful request! Data is " + data.toString());
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Result of `console.log(jqXHR)` if I add any code to servlet is always the same - `Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}`.

Here is code of servlet

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class);

  @Override
  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Start calling safe service");
        safeService(request,response);
        LOGGER.info("End calling safe service");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info("Error while processing loginServlet ",e);
        LOGGER.error("Error while processing loginServlet ",e);
    }

  }

  protected void safeService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // If I add this code, script calls error function
    /*response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");*/

    response.getWriter().print("welcome.html");


    // Or even this code.
    /*response.getWriter().flush();
    response.getWriter().close();*/
  }

}
```

Log is clean, there is not any of runtime exception.

Comment: you posting json and add datatype as text man

Comment: what is the error in your browser console

Comment: Examine the HTTP response in your browser's dev tools network tab; I suspect you'll find it's failing and this has nothing whatsoever to do with the client-side of the connection.

Comment: i would check the `url`, since this says:  `login`, most likely this is wrong and not returning an ajax response of type `text`  You should also remove dataType of `text` as that is almost never needed, if ever.  The `dataType` property here is what you expect to be returned from the ajax response.  If this is not type `text` it will cause error.

Comment: I check url, servlet receives data correctly. And, even I change it to full path, http://localhost:8181/library/login, it still doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, T.J. Crowder, I don't understand, what do you mean exactly? I use Chrome, its dev tools have only 3 pages, Elements, Console, Sources, and I put in question result of console.log()

Comment: From the error message (specifically `status: 0`) it seems that you're refreshing the page before the ajax call is executed, that may happen if you're submitting a `form`. Probably `#login-button` is a `form` submit `input` element.

Comment: You right `<form class="login-form">
    <input id="userLogin" type="text" name="user-login" placeholder="Enter login"/>
    <input id="userPassword" type="password" name="user-password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
    <input id="login-button" type="submit" value="Log in"/>
</form>`, how should I change it?

Comment: I change submit to button, and it helps))